# javascript onclick event to open a model in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatables

I am using datatables to show the values in grid, I implemented javascript on click event to open a modal and also this modal shows all the values in the clicked row. now whereever i click on the table row the modal is opening . now i want to prevent that and it should open onclicking of a certain column. My code is like this

```
(function() {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('load', run, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent('onload', run);
    }

    function run() {
      var t = document.getElementById('myTable');
      t.onclick = function(event) {
        $('#modal2').modal();
        event = event || window.event; //IE8
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        while (target && target.nodeName != 'TR') { // find TR
          target = target.parentElement;
        }
        //if (!target) { return; } //tr should be always found
        var cells = target.cells; //cell collection - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement
        //var cells = target.getElementsByTagName('td'); //alternative
        if (!cells.length || target.parentNode.nodeName == 'THEAD') {
          return;
        }
        var f1 = document.getElementById('prdctid');
        var f2 = document.getElementById('prdctname');
        var f3 = document.getElementById('prdctmodel');
        var f4 = document.getElementById('prdctversion');
        var f5 = document.getElementById('prdctlanguage');
        f1.value = cells[1].innerHTML;
        f2.value = cells[2].innerHTML;
        f3.value = cells[3].innerHTML;
        f4.value = cells[4].innerHTML;
        f5.value = cells[5].innerHTML;
        //console.log(target.nodeName, event);
      });
  }

})();
```

I tried the following code it is working only for first row.

```
(function() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', run, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', run);
  }

  function run() {
    // var t = document.getElementById('myTable');
    // t.onclick = function(event) {
    $('#myTable').on('click', 'tr td:eq(4)', function(event) {
      $('#modal2').modal();
      event = event || window.event; //IE8
      var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
      while (target && target.nodeName != 'TR') { // find TR
        target = target.parentElement;
      }
      //if (!target) { return; } //tr should be always found
      var cells = target.cells; //cell collection - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement
      //var cells = target.getElementsByTagName('td'); //alternative
      if (!cells.length || target.parentNode.nodeName == 'THEAD') {
        return;
      }
      var f1 = document.getElementById('prdctid');
      var f2 = document.getElementById('prdctname');
      var f3 = document.getElementById('prdctmodel');
      var f4 = document.getElementById('prdctversion');
      var f5 = document.getElementById('prdctlanguage');
      f1.value = cells[1].innerHTML;
      f2.value = cells[2].innerHTML;
      f3.value = cells[3].innerHTML;
      f4.value = cells[4].innerHTML;
      f5.value = cells[5].innerHTML;
      //console.log(target.nodeName, event);
    });
  }

})();
```

Comment: I'd recommend to user more obvious variable names. `f1` to `f7` are really bad variable names.

Comment: Thats Ok, i will change the variable names,But functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is slightly off.

`$('#myTable').on('click', 'tr td:eq(4)', function(event) {`

should be

`$('#myTable tr').on('click', 'td:eq(4)', function(event) {`

Your original method would apply the listener to the table, and then each `tr` and find the `td` that is #4. That's #4 on the original selector - `#myTable`, of which there is only one. The alteration will apply the listener to each `tr` on the `table`, and find the `td` that is #4 *on each row*.

As an aside, it's great that you've introduced jQuery into your code, but you should now change everything in the file to use it. Get rid of the vanilla JS (`.innerHTML`, `document.getElementById`, `target.parentElement`, etc.) and use the jQuery equivalents. (`$jqEl.html()`, `$('#id')` and `$jqEl.parent()`).

[Here's a fiddle with the amended selector.](https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/o2gxgz9r/4418/)

I'd suggest refactoring your code to someting like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $table = $('#myTable');
    var $modal2 = $('#modal2');
    $modalProductIdInput = $('#prdctid');
    $modalProductNameInput = $('#prdctname');
    // etc etc

    $table.on('click', 'tr td:eq(4)', function(event) {
        $modal2.modal();
        var $clickedCell = $(this);
        var $parentRow = $clickedCell.parent();
        var $rowCells = $parentRow.children()
        var productId = $rowCells[1];
        var productName = $rowCells[2];
        // etc etc

        $modalProductIdInput.value = productId;
        $modalProductNameInput.value = productName;
    });
});
```

I've not tested the above, but it looks roughly right. Hope this helps!